# Remote administer Network Policy Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, nps

In our domain I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine "GWY" with the Network Policy and Access Services role installed. From this machine I can open the Network Policy Server management console to administer this role.

However, I have another Server 2008 R2 machine "WKS" in the domain where we have all the management consoles installed so we can manage all the servers from one location. I cannot find how to access the Network Policy Server console on this machine though.

Answer (score 4):

The Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows Server 2008 R2 do *not* include the MMC snap-in for managing the Network Policy Server; the snap-in is installed only on servers where the NPS role is actually enabled.

From a server which has the NPS role enabled, you can run `mmc.exe`, add the NPS snap-in to it and have it connect to a remote server; but you can't do the same from a computer which has only the RSAT package but not the NPS role.

Answer (score 0):

After you install NPS, you can administer NPS servers:

- Locally, by using the NPS Microsoft
  Management Console (MMC) snap-in, the
  static NPS console in Administrative
  Tools, or the network shell (Netsh)
  commands for NPS.
- From a remote NPS server, by using
  the NPS MMC snap-in, the Netsh
  commands for NPS, or Remote Desktop
  Connection.
- From a remote workstation, by using
  Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: Sure, I understand this, but how do I locate the NPS MMC snap-in on a server that is not running NPS itself. The "Remote Server Administration Tools" Feature doesn't appear to include this even though it suggests it does with the "Network Policy and Access Services Tools" sub-feature.

Comment: You can't locate it, because it just isn't there, sorry :-(